# How to use ORM in C#?

Tags: c#, orm

I'm writing an OOP project, need to map the object oriented domain into the database, storing objects into the database, I worked with hibernate of java before, now I look for the same thing in C#.
I heard about NDatabase but I dont use it, any one here know and work with it?

Comment: What are your requirements? There are many, many ORMs in .NET, in various stages of maturity and convenience. Not to mention the push to micro-ORMs.

Comment: You should consider non relational databases as well. There are many options these days.

Comment: I start working with EF now. I didn't know about many options, thanks any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my professional work, I really like EntityFramework. it's powerful and pretty straightforward to use. Here is the guideline to work with (provided by Microsoft): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) - .net port of hibernate.

Also, take a look at [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)

I think, choosing an ORM solution depends on the database you gonna use. If you're sure it's **Sql Server**, definitely go for **Entity Framewrok** since all the advanced features (like [code-first](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx)) are supported there out of the box. If you go for **Oracle**, I would suggest **NHibernate** especially since you already know Hibernate

Comment: Code first was available in NHibernate many years befor EF. Unless you want to support some obscure database like Ingress, you should pick ORMs depending on their features, not the database you are going to use

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos hhm, I really thought there are no code-first and migraitons in NHibernate... Btw, I remember picking EF for Oracle database and it was a horrible decision. Many of the cool EF features aren't supported for Oracle (unless you buy a commercial provider). The whole development process was really painful :( I wish i picked something like BLToolkit

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend [EntityFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399572%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Hope i could help.